# Database to checkbox feild in django

Tags: html, database, django, checkbox, django-views

How to create a checkboxs field in html with django as backend and how to get the value of the selected checkbox back to the view for more processing

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/? Please read the online documentation about forms and modelforms (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
class Sample(models.Model):
    checkbox = models.BooleanField(blank=False, null=False, default=True)
```

In the template you just simply

```
{{ object.checkbox }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/